# Is is possible to define a custom mapping deriving from NgAttr in AngularDart?

Tags: angularjs-directive, dart, angular-dart

I'd like to define a new mapping annotation. For instance, wouldn't it be nice if @NgAttr added the mustache (the braces {{ and }}) automatically if the attribute looks like a controller value? So that it doesn't matter whether I write

```html
    <pui-input pattern="{{ctrl.pattern}}" ng-model="ctrl.value">
```

or

```html
    <pui-input pattern="ctrl.pattern" ng-model="ctrl.value">
```

Is it possible to add a custom mapping to AngularDart? My first approach was to simply derive from NgAttr, but it doesn't work because annotations must not contain methods in Dart:

```dart
    /**
     * When applied as an annotation on a directive field specifies that
     * the field is to be mapped to DOM attribute with the provided [attrName].
     * The value of the attribute to be treated as a string, equivalent
     * to `@` specification.
     * If the value of the attribute looks like a property of a controller, it
     * is surrounded by a mustache ({{ }}) if it is missing.
     */
    class PuiAttr extends AttrFieldAnnotation {
      final mappingSpec = '@';
      const PuiAttr(String attrName) : super(attrName);

      String get attrName => addMustache(super.attrName);

      String addMustache(String attrName)
      {
        if (attrName.indexOf("{{") == 0) // Todo: find a nice regexp
          if (attrName.indexOf("\.")>0)
              return "{{$attrName}}";
        return attrName;
      }
    }
```

Please note the mustaches are only an example. My question is whether it's possible to add custom mappings to the standard set @NgAttr, @NgOneWay, @NgTwoWay, @NgOneWayOneTime and @NgCallback.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: AngularDart 0.10.0 declares NgAttr, NgOneWay and so on deprecated. So chance are my question is deprecated, too.
Google didn't tell me what's going to replace Ng* when I kindly asked it :). Does anybody know?